# Windows Portable - Service Reference 5 seconds timeout

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I've got a Portable Class Library (WP7.1, Win8) and a service reference. If the service is (temporarily) unavailable, a call results in 5 seconds in a NotFound error.
I want to increase that timeout of 5 seconds to 10 seconds, but nothing works. SendTimeout, ReceiveTimeout, OpenTimeout, CloseTimeout (all on Binding) do have default values which are not 5 seconds. Changing them does not matter.
I've got no clue why the timeout is only 5 seconds?

Comment: What about receiveTimeout and sendTimeout

Comment: See edit, tried SendTimeout, ReceiveTimeout, OpenTimeout, CloseTimeout. 5 seconds is no default value I could find...